# Como enviar um APPEND entre paginas HTML

Tags: javascript

Olá! O que eu gostaria é que quando o meu usuario clicar em "adicionar carrinho" na pagina 1, fosse adicionado um append na pagina 2.

Atualmente eu tenho o append configurado corretamente na minha pagina 2

HTML PAGINA 1:

```
    <button type="button" id="btnCompra" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i> Adicionar ao carrinho</button>
```

HTML PAGINA 2:

```
    <div class="container-fluid divProdCarrinho"> 
        <div class="row" id="modeloProdutos">
           <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6"> 
             <img src="img/arroz.jpg" id="imagenzinha"> 
             <p id="descricaoProduto">...</p> 
    </div> </div> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (que funciona, pois todos os elementos são da mesma pagina):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#botaoPagina1').click (function(){
        var template = $('.divProdCarrinho').html();
        $("#bodyPrincipal").append(template);
    });
```

JAVASCRIPT (que gostaria que funcionasse, onde o butonAdd é elemento da pagina 1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#botaoPagina2').click (function(){
        var template = $('.divProdCarrinho').html();
        $("#bodyPrincipal").append(template);
        alert(template);
    });
```

Comment: como assim na "pagina 2"? só é possível fazer `append` na pagina que está carregada no navegador. Não ficou claro como está essa navegação, mas precisa passar um parametro para a outra página, por querystring por exemplo, e fazer o append no script da própria página

Comment: Utilize o `localStorage` para passar os dados de uma página para outra.

Comment: Ricardo basicamente eu quero dar um append na pagina 2 com elementos da pagina 1, mas nao sei se é possivel

Comment: Valdeir é possível eu salvar os elementos em localStorage da pagina 1 e dar um append com essas informações na pagina 2?

Comment: @WeslleyFillipe com o `localStorage` sim. Você salva o HTML numa página e, ao carregar a outra, você captura o HTML gravado na página anterior.

Comment: Valdeir, tentei dar um "localStorage.setItem('modeloProduto', $('.divProdCarrinho').html());" mas retornou "undefined", ja que essa div só existe na pagina 2. O meu objetivo era adicionar uma div na pagina 2 apos clicar no botao da pagina 1